# how do I make rounded corners on hovers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, rounded-corners

I'm making a theme for wordpress. My navigation bar has rounded corners like apple's site. I want to add a hover style to it, but I can't get it to hover with rounded corners, like apple's nav bar does. I'm using a big image for the background and using wordpress 3's menu system. So, how can I hover the first and last item on the bar? Thanks for helping.

Comment: How are you making the rounded corners?

Comment: the background image has rounded corners.

Comment: really - background images are nasty. I recommend [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/) for all your rounded corner goodness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to have a different background image for the "hover" style.

Comment: I know, and I have created it. but I really don't know how can I use a different image for the first and last item. I'm using the custom menu for wordpress, so I don't know how can I use a different css class for the first and last item. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ... well is wordpress giving you classes or something on the menu elements?  Have you used Firebug or some other debugger to look at the menu elements and see what wordpress generates?

Comment: yes, wordpress is indeed giving it an id. sio if I use that, can I make it?

Comment: If it's possible to identify the menu elements involved, *and* there's code to do something like set an additional "hovering" class (which is probably true or you would not have gotten this far :-)  then you should be able to have the "hovering" CSS just set a different "background-image" style.

Answer (score 2):

With javascript you can select and change whatever you want but if you just want to use css, you´ll have to apply the `:hover` to the parent of all button sub-elements so that you can select all sub-elements using css. However, that excludes older versions of IE as they don´t support `:hover` on elements other than `a` tags.

Example:

```
.button:hover {
  // 
}
.button:hover .main_section {
  // change to main section of button on hover
}
.button:hover .left_part {
  // change to left side on hover
}
.button:hover .right_part {
  // change to right side on hover
}
```